# Babel (gulp-babel) Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm using `gulp`, `gulp-babel`, which is causing an error.
I don't know how I can use module (ES6) because, when I try to import another file into this, it shows me this message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

I know the problem is after code has transpiled, because, I tried linking to code that's not transpiled, and it works perfectly.

These are my files.

**app.js** *(Where I want to use import to get another module...)

*Note: Using `require` from CommonJS project, also does not work.*

```
import a from "./comun.js"; //This doesn't work
class Player{
    contructor(){...}
}
```

**comun.js** *(Where i want to get a const from)*

```
export const a = 1;
```

**index.html** *(Html file) (File transpiled)*

```
<script src="./dist/js/app.js" type="module"></script>
```

And this is my ***gulpfile.babel.js*** (It's working perfectly)

```
const gulp = require ('gulp');
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
function transpileToES5() {
    return  gulp.src('./assets/js/*.js')
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
}

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.watch(['./assets/js/*.js'], transpileToES5)
});
```

And finally. This is my ***.babelrc*** file (I tried with commonjs, systemjs, amd... Nothing works )

```
{
    "presets" : ["@babel/env"],
    "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

This is the Error:
[image: SHOW CAPTURE OF THE ERROR ON THE BROWSER]

This is the line causing the error:
[image: SHOW CAPTURE OF THE WRONG LINE ON THE BROWSER]

Comment: Is there no answer to this?  I'm dealing with the exact same thing trying to get my code working in IE11 and adding core-js 3.

Comment: No, I'm finally using **webpack**. Because this was "impossible" for me. But you can check  bundlers tools like **Webpack, Browserify even CommonJS, RequireJS**. There are many information about them and it solve your problem. Gulp needs a bundler tool probably (some navigator doesn't support ES6 modules yet, like IE11), that was my conclusion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. You have to use Browserify + Babelify + Gulp. More info here:

https://medium.com/@hey.aaron/getting-import-export-working-es6-style-using-browserify-babelify-gulp-5hrs-of-life-eca7786e44cc

```
    return browserify({
    entries: ['./src/js/index.js'],
    debug: true,
    transform: [
      babelify.configure({ presets: ['@babel/preset-env'] }),
    ],
  })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
```